# Move points to nearest unoccupied grid position

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, geometry, data-visualization

I have a random distribution of points in 2D space like so:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr, labels = datasets.make_moons()
arr, labels = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=3)
pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['x', 'y']).plot.scatter('x', 'y', s=1)
```

[image]

I'm trying to assign each of these points to the nearest unoccupied slot on an imaginary hex grid to ensure the points don't overlap. The code I'm using to accomplish this goal produces the plot below. The general idea is to create the hex bins, then iterate over each point and find the minimal radius that allows the algorithm to assign that point to an unoccupied hex bin:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

def get_bounds(arr):
  '''Given a 2D array return the y_min, y_max, x_min, x_max'''
  return [
    np.min(arr[:,1]),
    np.max(arr[:,1]),
    np.min(arr[:,0]),
    np.max(arr[:,0]),
  ]

def create_mesh(arr, h=100, w=100):
  '''arr is a 2d array; h=number of vertical divisions; w=number of horizontal divisions'''
  print(' * creating mesh with size', h, w)
  bounds = get_bounds(arr)
  # create array of valid positions
  y_vals = np.arange(bounds[0], bounds[1], (bounds[1]-bounds[0])/h)
  x_vals = np.arange(bounds[2], bounds[3], (bounds[3]-bounds[2])/w)
  # create the dense mesh
  data = np.tile(
    [[0, 1], [1, 0]],
    np.array([
      int(np.ceil(len(y_vals) / 2)),
      int(np.ceil(len(x_vals) / 2)),
    ]))
  # ensure each axis has an even number of slots
  if len(y_vals) % 2 != 0 or len(x_vals) % 2 != 0:
    data = data[0:len(y_vals), 0:len(x_vals)]
  return pd.DataFrame(data, index=y_vals, columns=x_vals)


def align_points_to_grid(arr, h=100, w=100, verbose=False):
  '''arr is a 2d array; h=number of vertical divisions; w=number of horizontal divisions'''
  h = w = len(arr)/10
  grid = create_mesh(arr, h=h, w=w)

  # fill the mesh
  print(' * filling mesh')
  df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['x', 'y'])
  bounds = get_bounds(arr)
  # store the number of points slotted
  c = 0
  for site, point in df[['x', 'y']].iterrows():
    # skip points not in original points domain
    if point.y < bounds[0] or point.y > bounds[1] or \
       point.x < bounds[2] or point.x > bounds[3]:
      raise Exception('Input point is out of bounds', point.x, point.y, bounds)

    # assign this point to the nearest open slot
    r_y = (bounds[1]-bounds[0])/h
    r_x = (bounds[3]-bounds[2])/w
    slotted = False
    while not slotted:

      bottom = grid.index.searchsorted(point.y - r_y)
      top = grid.index.searchsorted(point.y + r_y, side='right')
      left = grid.columns.searchsorted(point.x - r_x)
      right = grid.columns.searchsorted(point.x + r_x, side='right')
      close_grid_points = grid.iloc[bottom:top, left:right]

      # store the position in this point's radius that minimizes distortion
      best_dist = np.inf
      grid_loc = [np.nan, np.nan]
      for x, col in close_grid_points.iterrows():
        for y, val in col.items():
          if val != 1: continue
          dist = euclidean(point, (x,y))
          if dist < best_dist:
            best_dist = dist
            grid_loc = [x,y]

      # no open slots were found so increase the search radius
      if np.isnan(grid_loc[0]):
        r_y *= 2
        r_x *= 2
      # success! report the slotted position to the user
      else:
        # assign a value other than 1 to mark this slot as filled
        grid.loc[grid_loc[0], grid_loc[1]] = 2
        df.loc[site, ['x', 'y']] = grid_loc
        slotted = True
        c += 1

        if verbose:
          print(' * completed', c, 'of', len(arr), 'assignments')
  return df


# plot sample data
df = align_points_to_grid(arr, verbose=False)
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', s=1)
```

[image]

I'm satisfied with the result of this algorithm, but not with the performance.

Is there a faster solution to this kind of hexbin assignment problem in Python? I feel others with more exposure to the [Linear Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) or the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) might have valuable insight into this problem. Any suggestions would be hugely helpful!

Comment: Do you know what the time-consuming operation is? If it is the `searchsorted`, you can calculate the hex coordinates from image coordinates directly (how exactly depends on your grid). Also, you could iterate the hex cells in rings around the query point to avoid searching the same cells multiple times. Again, it depends on how you organize your grid.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have been thinking about your comment that "you can calculate the hex coordinates from image coordinates directly" but I can't see how to do this--could you say more about what you mean? If you happen to have access to a little code example I'd be super grateful if you could send it on! I got a slight speed boost by slotting the point in the first available position rather than finding the optimal position in the search radius but I'm looking for bigger speed gains...

Comment: [This page](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) seems to be a good starting point. The section you are looking for is "Pixel to Hex".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out assigning each point to the first available grid spot within its current radius was sufficiently performant.

For others who end up here, my lab wrapped this functionality into a little [Python package](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/pointgrid) for convenience. You can `pip install pointgrid` and then:

```
from pointgrid import align_points_to_grid
from sklearn import datasets

# create fake data
arr, labels = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=5)

# get updated point positions
updated = align_points_to_grid(arr)
```

`updated` will be a numpy array with the same shape as the input array `arr`.