# Move points to nearest unoccupied grid position (different)

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of X "data points" with x and y coordinates and I want to assign them to a MxN grid, such that a "grid point" is occupied once. To simplify the question I here state that the number of "data points" and the number of "grid points" is identical.

For me the acceptable criterion is when the sum of difference between all "data point" and the selected "grid point" to the square is minimized.

For sure I can do this using a brute force method but there is a factorial of X number of possibilities, i.e. app. about 5*10^8 possibilities when you have 12 "data points".

Is there an elegant algorithm to do it with minimum computational effort less than O(n!)?

Just to visualize the problem I show an example with 6 "grid points" (A to F) in blue and "data points" (1 to 6) in red.

[image]

It is just interesting to see, that "3" is nearest point to "B", but then "1" is very far from the next point. Intuitively the human eye assigns trivially 2->A  4->C  6->E  5->F but it assigns non-trivial 1->B and 3->D. And this is what I want to reach programmatically.

There is already a question with the same name, but there was no discussion about algorithm,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570283/move-points-to-nearest-unoccupied-grid-position).

Comment: I have seen similar problems and as far as I can tell, there is no single criteria that guarantees an optimal solution. There are different heuristics but each one of them will fail in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a variant of the [balanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#/Balanced_assignment), or equivalently, the problem of finding a minimal matching in a balanced, weighted bipartite graph. Specifically, your problem is actually a bit more restricted, since the edge weights correspond to spacial distance, and certain  properties (e.g. the triangle inequality theorem) hold.

Have a look at the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) for a polynomial-time solution.